# Using colour and shapes together in legend

Tags: r, highcharts, shapes, pie-chart

What I am trying to do is plot a line chart that displays the comparative values amongst a few countries. The chart I get is:

[image]

The problem here is that both shapes and colours are listed in the legend. I want the legend to be just a combination of the group(using shape) and colour for that country. I am using this bit:

```
ggplot(data=Data,aes(x=Indicator,y=Numeric,group=Country,shape=group,colour=Country))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

The data is like this

```
    Indicator  Year             Country Numeric  data     group
1   All causes 2008         Afghanistan    1663  3.22  Very Low
2   All causes 2008             Albania     518  8.53       Low
3   All causes 2008             Algeria     591  8.64       Low
4   All causes 2008             Andorra     310 21.25      High
5   All causes 2008              Angola    1685 10.08       Low
6   All causes 2008 Antigua and Barbuda     682  9.07       Low
7   All causes 2008           Argentina     553 14.38    Medium
8   All causes 2008             Armenia     864  6.62  Very Low
9   All causes 2008           Australia     278 16.76    Medium
10  All causes 2008             Austria     335 16.17    Medium
11  All causes 2008          Azerbaijan     918  4.54  Very Low
12  All causes 2008             Bahamas     629 16.80    Medium
13  All causes 2008             Bahrain     408 11.41       Low
14  All causes 2008             Belgium     369 15.10    Medium
15  All causes 2008              Brazil     667  5.86  Very Low
16  All causes 2008          Costa Rica     400 30.61 Very High
17  All causes 2008         Ivory Coast    2567  6.82  Very Low
18  All causes 2008    Marshall Islands    2681 19.46      High
19  All causes 2008         Netherlands     323 19.69      High
20  All causes 2008         New Zealand     312 19.56      High
```

Could someone point me to what could be done to achieve this? I can't really break this down even though I spent quite a long time on this.

Comment: please put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: I think you are trying to put too much information on a one chart. It will be very difficult to identify the countries from the colors of the lines for example. Maybe you should try some faceting, or plotting averaged values depending on the group ?

Comment: Technically, since the x axis is categorical, it's a parallel coordinates plot, not a line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Change `group` -> `Country` in the `shape` argument.

```
ggplot(data=Data,aes(x=Indicator,y=Numeric,group=Country,shape=Country,colour=Country))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

Comment: Oh, `group` is a column in the dataset.  In that case, since you are using 2 separate variables as scales, of course you get two separate legends.  How do you envisage them being merged?